# Magento product price not showing on catalog_product/edit page

Tags: products, development

I am inserting a simple product programmatically.

the price is displaying on the grid but not on the (admin)form when I try to edit the product price. it is displaying as zero

```
$new_product->setName($sortedData['description'])
                    ->setAttributeSetId(9)
                    ->setTypeId('simple') 
                    ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now'))
                    ->setWebsiteIds(array(1))
                    ->setStatus(1)
                    ->setTaxClassId(1)
                    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                    ->setTag($sortedData['printer_compatibility'])
                    ->setCategoryIds($category)
                    ->setSupplierCode($sortedData['dynamic_supply_code'])
                    ->setSku($sortedData['dynamic_supply_code'])
                    ->setCostExTax($sortedData['reseller_price_ex_gst'])
                    ->setManufacturer($this->fetchManufacturerOption($sortedData['manufacturer_name']))
                    ->setColor($this->addAttributeValue('color', $sortedData['cartridge_type']))
                    ->setMarkUpPercentage(10)
                    ->setPrice($this->calculatePrice($sortedData['reseller_price_ex_gst'], 10))
                    ->setCustomPrice($this->calculatePrice($sortedData['reseller_price_ex_gst'], 10))
                    ->setOriginalCustomPrice($this->calculatePrice($sortedData['reseller_price_ex_gst'], 10))
                    //->setPricePerPage()
                    ->setManufacturerCode($sortedData['manufacturer_oem_code'])
                    ->setWeight($sortedData['product_weight'])
                    //->setPageYield($sortedData['cartridge_yield'])
                    ->setPageYield($this->filterPageYield($sortedData['cartridge_yield'], $sortedData['cartridge_type']))
                    ->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()))
                    ->addImageToMediaGallery(getcwd()."/images/{$sortedData['dynamic_supply_code']}.jpg", array('image','thumbnail','small_image'), false, false)
                    ->setCubicMeasurement($sortedData['cubic_measurement'])
                    ->setStockData(array(
                                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                                    'manage_stock'=>1, //manage stock
                                    'min_sale_qty'=>1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                    'max_sale_qty'=>2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                                    'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                                    'qty' => $sortedData['stock_on_hand'] //qty
                                )
                    );

            $new_product->save();
```

Comment: try catalog reindexing

Comment: already tried this. it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this on the frontend (or in an sql/data install) you must initialize the Magento app as Admin, if you have `flat_catalog` option enabled on your store, maybe you are saving this data to: `catalog_flat_{store_id}` table and not in EAV tables, you should set the `store_id` too.

BTW Check reindex too.

Comment: I am doing a custom module on admin. everything is saved properly except for the price

Comment: Ok, try to save the product, then set the price and save again.  Can you specify your magento version and index configuration? indexes works different in CE and EE

Comment: I am at CE 1.9 note that the price is displaying on the product grid. but when I click the product to edit the price.. it is displayed as zero